# Magento - Add to Cart Error

Tags: ajax, json, magento, cart

I'm getting this error after add/remove item to/from cart. Add to Cart button does ajax call to add item to the cart. This kind of json string which will be used in top cart:

[image]

I'm stuck. Can you tell me where should I start from to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "Add to Cart" button does not work asynchrounisly in Magento's default behaviour. That means that you installed/developped a module to do this. For us to help you, we need to know what is it.
Anyways, this looks like a `Zend_Dump` or maybe a `die`: make a search in your files for these strings and see what comes up

Answer (score 1):

Use Netbeans and Xdebug.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Place a breakpoint on the /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php inside this function:

```
/**
 * Adding catalog product object data to quote
 *
 * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
 */
protected function _addCatalogProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $qty = 1)
{
    $newItem = false;
    $item = $this->getItemByProduct($product);
    if (!$item) {
        $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
        $item->setQuote($this);
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            $item->setStoreId($this->getStore()->getId());
        }
        else {
            $item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        }
        $newItem = true;
    }

    /**
     * We can't modify existing child items
     */
    if ($item->getId() && $product->getParentProductId()) {
        return $item;
    }

    $item->setOptions($product->getCustomOptions())
        ->setProduct($product);

    // Add only item that is not in quote already (there can be other new or already saved item
    if ($newItem) {
        $this->addItem($item);
    }

    return $item;
}
```

HTH